# How to print redis queries on console from Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, redis

Is there any way to print **Redis** queries on console if we're doing any CRUD operation on Redis database from Spring Boot application like the way we do using **jpa.show_sql** ?

I did a web search but did find any yet.

I have created Bug here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/issues/1586 (formerly DATAREDIS-1014)